# Formula to calculate the frequency of gravitational waves emitted by two bodies inspiral?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, black-holes, gravitational-waves, ligo

Is there a small straightforward equation which can give the approximate frequency of the gravitational waves emitted by the inspiral of two bodies?

Comment: Do you mean frequency as a function of time?

Comment: @RobJeffries    More like the starting frequency from where I should look for the Gravitational wave signal assuming I was LIGO. I'm sorry if this question is trivial I am new to Gravitational waves.

Comment: I think this is possibly a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174333/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To leading order, the angular frequency of radial motion in a binary inspiral obeys the equation
$$ \frac{d \omega}{dt} = \frac{96}{5} \left( \frac{G \mathcal{M}}{c^3} \right)^{5/3} \omega^{11/3} $$
where $\mathcal{M}$ is the so-called chirp mass, defined by
$$ \mathcal{M} = \left( \frac{m_1 m_2}{(m_1 + m_2)^{1/3}} \right)^{3/5}. $$

The frequency of the gravitational wave signal will be twice the orbital frequency. That is, the observed frequency of the signal is
$$ \nu = 2 \frac{\omega}{2\pi} = \frac{\omega}{\pi}. $$
You can use these equations to estimate the chirp mass of the system $\mathcal{M}$ using $\nu$ and $\dot{\nu}$, or vice versa. Given a sensible initial condition, you can solve for $\omega(t)$ or $\nu(t)$ analytically and find the evolution of the signal frequency.

Note that the differential equation for $\omega$ implies that $\omega$ increases monotonically ($\dot{\omega} > 0$). This equation also predicts that $\omega$ will diverge in finite time, which corresponds to the collision event and the end of orbital motion.

Comment: Could you please add a reference source for these formulas?

Comment: @magma The differential equation for $\omega$ is stated explicitly in the beginning of section II C of [this paper](http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevD.49.2658), for example. See _The Classical Theory of Fields_ by Landau and Lifshitz for a complete treatment of the subject.