# What is the typical order of magnitude (*numerical* in $\rm Hz$, not expression) of frequency of a gravitation wave?

Tags: frequency, gravitational-waves

What is the typical order of magnitude of frequency of a gravitation wave ?

I have read [Frequency of gravitational waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174333/)

but they only give expression, without any quantitative numerical answer for the order of magnitude.

Comment: Surely that depends on characteristic frequencies of the process which it eminated from. You are asking a very broad question at this point, so no answer is possible. What, for example, is the typical order of magnitude of an electromagnetic wave? That is completely context-dependent.

Comment: See also [Gravitational waves frequency](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/247513)

Comment: Thank you @Rob jeffries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are asking about [detectable gravitational waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_observation_of_gravitational_waves#Direct_observation) - for example the black-hole/black-hole merger signals as detected by LIGO, then typical frequency ([tens to hundreds of Hz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gravitational_wave_observations)) is in the audible range.

If you are asking about gravitational waves in general, then there can be vibrations at any frequency at which two masses can move relative to each other. So from << 10^-15 Hz to  >> 10^15 Hz. Most of these waves would be undetectable by existing (or any imaginable future) technology.